# How to customize a field of the model before storing in database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, mutators

I have a model like this :

```
class Article extends Model {
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'body',
    'img_profile', // store name of image
    ];
}
```

And a controller like this:

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request){
    $article = Auth::user()->articles()->create($request->all());
    return redirect('articles');
}
```

And a form like this:

```
{!! Form::model($article = new \App\Article,['url' => 'articles','files' => true ]) !!}
{!! Form::text('title', null ) !!}
{!! Form::textarea('body', null) !!}
{!! Form::file ('img_profile', '') !!}
{!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I submit the form, the `img_profile` field is stored default cached file which is `/private/var/tmp/phpceBMP2`.But I just want to update `file_name` in `img_profile`.

How can I change the value of the `img_profile` request before storing it in database?

Answer (score 4):

You should use [mutator](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for `Article` model this way:

```
public function setImgProfileAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['img_profile'] = '/private/var/tmp/phpceBMP2/'. $value;
}
```

However you should think if you really want to store the path in DB this way. What if you will want to change it in future? You will have to update all the records?

Comment: As default Laravel saves the `img_profile`  value as `/private/var/tmp/phpceBMP2`, now I want to customize it into the image's name such as  `img_file_name`.